# ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 1) using woocomerce rest api

Tags: apache, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to use woocommerce rest api to update product stock quantity and price, using PUT Method, but after running the code, it gives me error:

Response Code 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /wc-api/v2/products/15542
on this server.

I am using centos 6 server, i have commented on modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf [id "960032"] by researching on web. but still it doesnt work.

```
public void updateStock() {
    String nonce = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32);
    Map<String, String> paramMap = new TreeMap<>();
    paramMap.put("oauth_consumer_key", key);
    paramMap.put("oauth_timestamp", "" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 
1000));
    paramMap.put("oauth_nonce", nonce);
    paramMap.put("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> parameter : paramMap.entrySet()) {
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(parameter.getKey(), 
parameter.getValue()));
    }
    String encodedParams = 
URLEncoder.encode(URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC), ENC);
    String signature = getSignature("http://topvacuumparts.com/wc- 
api/v2/products/15542", encodedParams, "PUT");
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature", signature));
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "topvacuumparts.com", -1, "wc- 
api/v2/products/15542", URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC), null);
    HttpPut httpget = new HttpPut(uri);
    httpget.setHeader("X-Stream", "true");
    httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");        
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("stock_quantity", "20");
    ob.put("product", obj);
    StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
    httpget.setEntity(entity1);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Response Code " + 
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```

This is the Result:
Response Code 403
Json response
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wc-api/v2/products/15542
on this server

Comment: Which versions are you using? (modsecurity, CRS, and webserver)
What do you see in your webserver's error log/modsecurity's debug.log?
Are you your you have the id 960032 - looks like it's an old version, and since CRS 3.0 it doesn't exists.